# Share from Power BI data set to Postgresql (BI -> Posgresql)

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

There is a way to get the data from Power BI Data Set and store it on Postgresql?

As far as my research goes theres is a way to do that on SQL Server, but no to Postgresql.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that belong to the category of postgresql foreign data wrapper. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's posible than yo need a PRO Licence or other paid licence. You have a free month or you can do a external process that export it in a excel and read the excel with Powerbi.